# Mac: git diff - better colors?

Tags: macos, git, colors, diff

Is there a way to get better colors for git diff on a Mac?  Something more like Linux' colors.  In the diff, the lines that are removed are highlighted and colored, but added lines are grey.  Grey?! :)  (Granted, it's slightly bolded, but it's still hard to parse through the information when it's grey...)

Thanks!

Comment: Read about `color.diff.<slot>` and friends in `git help config`.

Comment: How much simpler can it get?!

Comment: Nm.  That works.  If you want to put it up as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of the parts of Git's diff are set with the `color.diff.<slot>` config parameters, where `<slot>` is the part of the diff, in this case `new`. [`git help config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) provides further information, but in short, set something like this in your Git config file:

```
[color "diff"]
    new = green
```

Or to set it with a command:

```
git config --global color.diff.new green
```

If, for some reason, you only want to set it in a certain repo, just run it without `--global`.

I recommend spending some time reading the configuration documentation: There are many things one can set in one's Git configuration to make Git more like one wants it.